# Implementing a Dirac Delta like function symbolically

Tags: replacement

I have an arbitrary expression where some terms are multiplied with a Dirac delta 'like' function d(x,y). For example,

> e^(ax+by+cz).d(x,y).d(a,c) + e^(ax+by+cz).d(x,y)+e^(ax+by+cz)

I need to get the answer

> e^(cy+by+cz) + e^(ay+by+cz) +e^(ax+by+cz)

All the d(x,y) function does is replace all the xs with ys in that particular product term. Kind of what the Dirac Delta function does, but without the integrals.

I think a /. expression should be able to do this task, but I am quite new to Mathematica so I can't get it right. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mathematica has a few built-in delta functions, including DiracDelta, KroneckerDelta, and DiscreteDelta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TagSet` (`/:`) allows this to be done with the dot product formatting:

```
d /: Dot[a_, d[x_, y_]] := a /. x -> y;
E^(a x + b y + c z).d[x, y].d[a, c] + E^(a x + b y + c z).d[x, y] + E^(a x + b y + c z)
```

> E^(a x + b y + c z) + E^(a y + b y + c z) + E^(b y + c y + c z)

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
(Exp[a x + b y + c z] /. {x -> y, a -> c}) + (Exp[a x + b y + c z] /. 
   x -> y) + Exp[a x + b y + c z]
```

I suspect if your /. is not behaving properly that you might be missing the parentheses (I know I was when I tried this). For multiple replacement rules, they should be given as a list (inside of {}), but a single replacement rule can be given by itself.

Output:

> $E^{a x+b y+c z}+E^{a y+b y+c z}+E^{b y+c y+c z}$

Comment: Thanks. But for this kind of solution you need to know the format of the function beforehand. In my problem what I get is like a 1000 term polynomial with all kinds of sines, exponentials, etc together with d[x,y] functions. So I am looking for a statement like 'Replace (anyfunction[x,y,anyvariable].d[x,y]) with (thatfunction[y,y,thatvariable) '

Comment: @RaviTharakaWijesekara Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I thought you were entering the ".d[x, y]" notation yourself, I didn't realize it was already part of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you would do it with a dot product, but you can always make the `d` a function.

```
eterm = E^(a*x + b*y + c*z)

d[x_, y_][f_] := f /. {x -> y}

d[a, c][d[x, y][eterm]] + d[x, y][eterm] + eterm
(*E^(a x + b y + c z) + E^(a y + b y + c z) + E^(b y + c y + c z)*)

d[a, c]@d[x, y]@eterm + d[x, y]@eterm + eterm
```

works too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exact expression you want to transform because you write `d(x,y)` rather than `d[x,y]`, but maybe the following is what you have:

```
expr = e^(a x + b y + c z).d[x, y].d[a, c] + e^(a x + b y + c z).d[x, y] + e^(a x + b y + c z);
expr /. Dot[a_, b__] :> (a /. Rule @@@ {b})
```

> $e^{a x+b y+c z}+e^{a y+b y+c z}+e^{b y+c y+c z}$